# Dynamic column naming during groupby agg

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to perform a general version of

```py
df.groupby([columns]).agg(new_name1=('col1':'min'),
                          new_name2=('col1':'max'),
                          new_name3=('col2':'mean'))
```

I would like to be able to specify the new column names dynamically so that this function is general.
ie -

```
d = {
     'new_name1':('col1':'min'), 
     'new_name2':('col1':'max'),
     'new_name3':('col2':'mean')
    }
```

And then use this dictionary in the agg, doing something like

```
groupby([columns]).agg(d)
```

Currently all I can do is

```
groupby([columns]).agg({'col1':['min', 'max'] 'col2':['mean']}).reset_index()
```

But that returns a dataframe where the aggregations down a level and I can't rename them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `**` to unpack dictionary and there is no syntax like `('col1':'min')`

```py
d = {
     'new_name1':('col1','min'), 
     'new_name2':('col1','max'),
     'new_name3':('col2','mean')
}


groupby([columns]).agg(**d)
```

Comment: @thefrollickingnerd Why it doesn't work? Show an example intput and output.

Comment: Apologies, I thought I had already tried this combination but apparently I had not. This does work. How frustrating! Could've avoided needing to post...

Answer (score 0):

```
    str1="df1.groupby('School').agg({})"

str2="new_name1=('Height','min'),new_name2=('Height','max'),new_name3=('Weight','mean')"#build as your need
eval(str1.format(str2))
```